# Tikz graph package: complete bipartite

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am wondering about the functionality of the tikz graph package and ran into the following issue.

I got this example form the *TikZ & PGF Manual for Version 2.10-CVS*:

```
\tikz \graph {
{a,b,c} -> [complete bipartite] {e,f,g}
};
```

Minor adjustments to the left hand side, the code still works.

```
\tikz \graph {
{$v_1$,$v_2$,$v_3$} -> [complete bipartite] {e,f,g}
};
```

After making the same adjustments to the right hand side, the code breaks.

```
\tikz \graph {
{$v_1$,$v_2$,$v_3$} -> [complete bipartite] {$r_1$,$r_2$,$r_3$}
};
```

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: Welcome to tex.stackexchange!! While I cannot answer the question **why?** I can say that you need to tell `\graph` that you are using *math nodes*: `\tikz \graph[math nodes] {
{v_1,v_2,v_3} -> [complete bipartite] {r_1,r_2,r_3}
};` works as expected. See PGF user manual, version 3.1.8b, page 295. HTH.

Comment: Probably irrelevant for the question, but that manual is quite old. Unless you're actually using v2.10, I'd look at a more recent manual. You may have installed documentation alongside the packages, and then you can open a terminal/command prompt, type `texdoc tikz`, and hit enter, to open the manual corresponding to the version of TikZ you have installed. The manual version mentioned by @sgmoye, which is the most recent one, can be found at https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf or https://texdoc.net/